# cant add products to shopping cart in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a shopping cart and am able to create one in mongodb but I can't add the products that are stored in the DB to the cart. It will just show an empty items array in the console.log as well as mongodb gui. Any help is appreciated.

```
const express = require('express');
const Carts = require('../repo/carts');


const router = express.Router();



router.post('/cart/products', async (req, res) => {

  Carts.findById(req.session.cartId, (err, foundCart) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    if (foundCart) {
      console.log(foundCart);
      Carts.update( { _id:req.session.cartId }, {
        $push: {
          items: {
            _id: req.body.productId,
            quantity: 1,
          },
        },
      });
    } else {
      if (!foundCart) {
        const newCart = new Carts({
          _id: req.session.cartId,
          items: [],
        });
        newCart.save();
      }
    } 
  });

  res.send('product added to cart!!');
});

module.exports = router;
```

carts schema for mongodb

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const cartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: String,
  items: [
    { quantity: Number, _id: String,}
  ] 
});

const Carts = new mongoose.model('Carts', cartSchema);

module.exports = Carts;
```

image of cart in mongodb robo3t
[image]

Comment: Check if it is indeed finding one. If it is, you should pass the id to push the items.                         


Carts.update(
    { _id:req.session.cartId }, 
    { $push: { tems: {
          _id: req.body.productId,
          quantity: 1,
        } } },
    done
);

Comment: i can console.log it so i assume its working. when i pass the id it still shows 0 elements as the value for items in robo3t

Comment: Could you share the new code, it is also possible to add a function as las parameter to capture any errors in the update.
By the way, in both scenarios you are console logging the same.

Comment: there are no errors being console logged. i have updated the code in the post.

Answer (score 1):

That err is for the findById, you can add a similar function for the update function and see why it is not working.
Also check if the id body id is received ok.

```
Carts.findById(req.session.cartId, (err, foundCart) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err) // This err is for the find by Id, not to the update function
    }
    if (foundCart) {
      console.log(foundCart)
      console.log(req.body.productId)
      Carts.update( 
        { _id:foundCart._id }, {
        $push: {
          items: {
            _id: req.body.productId,
            quantity: 1,
          },
        },
      },(err,updatedCart) => {
         if(err){
           console.log(err)
         }
     }
    );
    } else {
      if (!foundCart) {
        const newCart = new Carts({
          _id: req.session.cartId,
          items: [],
        });
        newCart.save();
      }
    } 
  });

  res.send('product added to cart!!');
});

module.exports = router;
```